# Should the angularjs2 node_modules when deploying to Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, angular

I'm developing a cloud endpoints application in Java and I want to use `angularjs2` as the front end for the application.

The web-app has the the modules it needs located in the `node_modules` folder.When I deploy this to the local dev-app server it works perfectly but the only downside is the time it take to deploy it.

So the question lies is if I am meant to include when deploying or is there a more optimal way?